# Markdown use on the profile page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, profile-page

Taking a gander at [my profile page](https://superuser.com/users/13241/josh-k) on superuser you'll notice that the Markdown *is not rendered*. In fact none of it renders.

Is this `feature-by-design` or simply not noticed? I love the use of Markdown, and have actually caught myself coding adding bolds and emphasis with *'s. I'd like to see it added to the profile page.

Comment: So do you want it to support Markdown or asking why it doesn't?

Comment: Yes. (11 to go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "about me" field is now Markdown-enabled!

(I agree we should have done this a year ago, but.. hey.. better late than never, right? *right?*)

Comment: Is it supposed to support [tag:tag] format? I'm not sure that it does, at present.

Comment: Never mind; it doesn't appear in the preview pane, which is a little confusing.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Good catch; that was an oversight. It will work in the preview as well after the next build.

Comment: @balpha: Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, below the text box it says:

> Basic HTML is Allowed.

So, I don't believe it is suppose to render Markdown, just basic HTML.

Comment: Well, yeah. But I **want** it to render Markdown. Hence the `[feature-request]`.

Comment: @Josh you specifically asked `Is this by-design or simply not noticed?`. I'm answering your question. So why the down vote?

Comment: I know (a) it doesn't render markdown, it bugs me that it doesn't. I wanted to know if it was overlooked (feature-by-design) or if they did it on purpose. I didn't feel it answered my question.